# Unable to change column reference in Access 2013

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I want to update the column reference for the ODBC SQL connection. The column name was changed in the SQL database.

I have updated the linked table manager, queries, macros, form references, and done a compact and repair. No issues reading data, but when (and only when) the form attempts to **write** to the database it references the non existing column name.

```
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'OldColumn'. (#207)
```

Where else would Access store column names? Is there a cache?

Comment: Delete the linked table and re-create it. If issue still happens, it's in you code or your objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could make the hidden objects and the system objects in MsAccess visible, in the table list would appear some extra tables. Look for `MSysObjects, MSysQueries and MSysRelationships`. On the side of SQL-server, are you sure there aren't any stored procedures that will execute after changing data? Think for example of autoincrement-values.

Comment: We don't have backend access, but it did appear to be an issue with the SQL database.

Comment: I would vote you up but I can't do it as a new user.